# Multiply a part of a matrix by a certain number

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to multiply 2 by numbers in the matrix that are between 10 and 20 and also by 3 by numbers in the matrix that are between 30 and 40and the other numbers stay in place

for example I have two matrix:

```
Var1   Var2  Var3
  20    40    50
  25    5      6
  20    13    45
  3     8     100
```

Finally, I want to get to this matrix

```
 Var1   Var2  Var3
  40     120   50
  25      5    6 
  40      26   45  
  3       8    100
```

Comment: So you don't want the values in column #3 to be multiplied?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
#Data
B <- structure(c(20L, 25L, 20L, 3L, 40L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 50L, 6L, 45L, 
100L), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"
)))

#Index
index1 <- which(B>=10 & B<=20)
index2 <- which(B>=30 & B<=40)
#Product
B[index1] <- 2*B[index1]
B[index2] <- 3*B[index2]

     Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]   40  120   50
[2,]   25    5    6
[3,]   40   26   45
[4,]    3    8  100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `apply` the function `ifelse`to the columns you want to multiply values in:

```
mat[,1:2] <- t(apply(mat[,1:2], 1, function(x) ifelse(x >= 20 & x <=30, x*2,
                                                      ifelse(x >= 30 & x <=40, x*3, x))))
```

Result:

```
mat
     Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]   40  120   50
[2,]   50    5    6
[3,]   40   13   45
[4,]    3    8  100
```

Data:

```
mat <- structure(c(20L, 25L, 20L, 3L, 40L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 50L, 6L, 45L, 
                 100L), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"
                 )))
```